# Redirect non-www to www *WITH* another rewrite already taking place

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, helicontech

This is a relatively standard question, but I cannot seem to get it to work on URLs that already have a rewrite going on.

For example, I have this URL:

```
http://example.com/this-is-rewritten/
https://example.com/this-is-rewritten/
```

should go to:

```
http://www.example.com/this-is-rewritten/
https://www.example.com/this-is-rewritten/
```

and I want to make sure that it is always WWW in front, if it is not a subdomain URL.  So, if we had:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/this-is-rewritten/
```

That should NOT go to WWW.  This is what I have so far, but it will send you to the under lying URL with querystring, not to the same "/this-is-rewritten/" url.  Also, the http or https should be preserved.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or if you only have a specific host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s (?:on(s)|off(s))
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That is taking me to [link](https://www../s/rec/this-is-rewritten/)

Also, this should not take you to httpS if http was the original request.  But, if we can get the domain in there and fix the https issue, this should work.

Comment: that second one does seem to work with the host - I will fully test tomorrow, but looks good.  thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's also a common solution from Helicon's FAQ. Works 99.9%

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works, but it tacks on the querystring to the end of the rewritten URL.

Comment: Easy! Just add '?' at the end:

RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3? [R=301,L]